# How to solve Axios GET request 404 error in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, axios

I want to display questions with related answers. Unfortunately, if I load a single `QuestionPage`, it is not showing all the answers. This is because I have spotted a logical error in the `./components/Answers.vue` component.

I think the problem is in my `fetch ()` function where the endpoint link is undefined (screenshot of the console error https://prnt.sc/198ebdx )

This [Answers](https://github.com/afsarpervez/testproject/blob/spa-1-error/resources/js/components/Answers.vue) component is used in [QuestionPage](https://github.com/afsarpervez/testproject/blob/spa-1-error/resources/js/pages/QuestionPage.vue), where I think the `Question` component is not referred correctly to the `Answer` component.

Comment: Perhaps you could add your code and screenshot inline, so we do not rely on the code in the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<answers :question="question"></answers>` in the `QuestionPage.vue` component should have a `v-if="question.id"` to prevent loading of the component, in case `question` defined in your `data()` function does not exist.

**Explanation**

The error is thrown in your console, because of an undefined variable used in your HTTP request.

Looking at your `Answers.vue` component, you have the following code in your `created` function:

```
created () {
    this.fetch(`/questions/${this.questionId}/answers`);
},
```

This question ID refers to your Props / Data structure in the same `Answers.vue`:

```
export default {
    props: ['question'],
    mixins: [highlight],
    data () {
        return {
            questionId: this.question.id,
            count: this.question.answers_count,
            answers: [],
            answerIds: [],
            nextUrl: null
        }
    }
}
```

In your `QuestionPage.vue` component, you're passing `question` as a prop to your `Answers.vue` component. However, this variable is probably undefined. You should check the result of this function first

```
mounted () {
    this.fetchQuestion ();
    //  alert(this.question)
    //  console.log(this.question)
},

methods: {
    fetchQuestion () {
        axios.get(`/questions/${this.slug}`).then(({data})=> {
          this.question = data.data
        }).catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
}
```

If that function does not have a result, make sure your `slug` prop is correct and handled by the back-end.

Comment: It is working now. I have added a v-if="question.id" in QuestionPage.Vue in the container div before loading both components (question and answers). But I couldn't understand why it needed to use v-if as I have sent models in the components by binding.

Comment: That is because the `Answers.vue` component is loaded **before** your `QuestionPage.vue` component loaded the question. Therefore, the variable is `undefined`. With `v-if` you ensure once the data is loaded, the if statement becomes true and loads the component. Vue handles the automatic re-rendering for you. If the answer worked for you, perhaps you could change the question to `answered` so it might help other people with a similar question.